# how to set urls in django to prevent similar job?

Tags: python, django

I practice how to use django to write a website
I finished one with model name = Traveltime
But I still have many to do (like: aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc below)
They are do similar job ,just the model name is different

I feel it duplicate and don't know how to do.
how can I edit my urls.py?? Please help me thank you!

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^travel/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.Traveltime}),
    url(r'^travel/result/$', views.object_result, {'model': models.Traveltime}),
    url(r'^travel/update/$', views.update),
    #I have many urls to set (below)
    url(r'^aaaaa/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.aaaaa}),
    url(r'^aaaaa/result/$', views.object_result, {'model': models.aaaaa}),
    url(r'^aaaaa/update/$', views.update),
    url(r'^bbbbb/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.bbbbb}),
    url(r'^bbbbb/result/$', views.object_result, {'model': models.bbbbb}),
    url(r'^bbbbb/update/$', views.update),
    url(r'^ccccc/$', views.object_list, {'model': models.ccccc}),
    url(r'^ccccc/result/$', views.object_result, {'model': models.ccccc}),
    url(r'^ccccc/update/$', views.ccccc),
```

views.py

```
def object_list(request, model):
    obj_list = model.objects.filter(image_elect='')   
    paginator = Paginator(obj_list, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    template_name = 'filterimgs/%s_list.html' % model.__name__.lower()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'object_list': obj_list,"contacts": contacts},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def update(request):
    travel = Traveltime.objects.filter(title=request.POST['title'])
    # travel.update(image_elect='asd')
    return redirect(object_result)

def object_result(request, model):
    obj_list = model.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(obj_list, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger: 
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    template_name = 'filterimgs/%s_result.html' % model.__name__.lower()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'object_list': obj_list,"contacts": contacts},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: was the answer you received helpful at all?  Do you need any further clarification/assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django url patterns are regular expressions, any grouped expression will be passed into the appropriate view as an additional parameter.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.object_list),
    url(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)/result/$', views.object_result),
    url(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)/update/$', views.update),
)
```

Then in your request you can

```
import importlib

def object_list(request, model_type):
    # use the model_type which is passed in from 
    # the URL to actually grab the proper model
    found = importlib.import_module('models.{0}'.format(model_type))
```

Python is gracious enough to allow you to import modules using a string .

Also, found is a lame name, so you should name it accordingly depending on what it's purpose is.

Comment: I try but got this error ````got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'````

Comment: try the edit, it's likely the word model is reserved at an outer scope.

Comment: @user2492364 okay i realized i still had definitions for your Traveltime model and your manually passing it in as part of the request.  Instead, rely on the URL containing the model name information, your view definition takes in the type that is expected and should look it up.